# How do i get value for (0008,0018) SOP Instance UID while sending C_Get request to Dicom server

Tags: dicom

I need to get a file from Dicom server.

But server do not send a valid pixel data unless i give (`0008,0018 i.e. SOP instance UID`), so if I give this SOP Instance UID (I already have this value from one of successful logs) then it works fine.

I have to no idea how and what value to put in *TAG (0008,0018)* while retrieving file using `C_Get`..

Comment: Which DICOM library you're using?

Comment: We are writing our own solution. We are not using any library.

Answer (score 2):

Usually you can retrieve the available `SOP Instance UIDs` from the server by sending a C-Find request.

The dicom servers mostly don't support relational queries. So it might be necessary to do several queries to get the SOP instance UIDs.

To find all the SOP Instance UID's you can make a query on `Study Level` to retrieve the Study Instance UID, then use this UID in a query on `Series level` to retrieve the list of Series Instance UID's, then query once for every Series Instance UID at `Image level` to retrieve all the SOP instances of that series.

Check the mandatory and optional attributes for the queries at `part 4 of the standard (section C.6)`

Comment: I did this process and I do have Stury UID and Series UID. But when I query IMAGE table with this series UID then I do not get SOP Instace UID in return. Please refer query and response copied below below:

Comment: Request:
(   0H,    0H): UL 0 (0H)
(   0H,    2H): UI 1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.2.1.1
(   0H,  100H): US 32 (20H)
(   0H,  110H): US 1 (1H)
(   0H,  700H): US 0 (0H)
(   0H,  800H): US 0 (0H)
(   8H,   18H): UI null
(   8H,   52H): CS IMAGE 
(  20H,    eH): UI 2.25.2.25.129780876084599113793693723938718889398
Response:
(   0H,    0H): UL 76 (4cH), 
(   0H,    2H): UI 1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.2.1.1 
(   0H,  100H): US 32800 (8020H) 
(   0H,  120H): US 1 (1H)
(   0H,  800H): US 257 (101H) 
(   0H,  900H): US 0 (0H)

Comment: I got this field now. Thanks for your support